# How to create Province, Cities and districts in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

Iam new to rails,I want create Province and under Province show cities,districts.I try to use acts_as_tree but it not full my idea, any idea you have?

Comment: What are the `relations` between those models?

Comment: province.rb   has_many :cities, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :districts, through: :cities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Models**

You'll want to look at the [`ancestry` gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)

This will give you the `acts_as_tree` functionality you desire; but more importantly, you'll want to consider your model structure:

```
#app/models/province.rb
Class Province < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :districts
    has_many :cities, source: :districts
end

#app/models/district.rb
Class District < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :province
   has_many :cities
end

#app/models/city.rb
Class City < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :district
end
```

Since you're new, here's how you would handle this in your routes etc:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :provinces do
   resources :districts #-> domain.com/provinces/2/districts/2
end
```

In your controller, you'll have this:

```
#app/controllers/provinces_controller.rb
Class ProvincesController < ApplicationController
   def index
       @provinces = Province.all 
   end

   def show
       @province = Province.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/provinces/show.html.erb
<% @province.districts.first.cities.each do |city| %>
    <%= city.name %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Ancestry**

If you wanted to make certain provinces / districts `children` of others, you'll want to use the `ancestry` gem - this will give you the ability to define `ancestors` to your specific records

I can explain more if you give me some specifics

---

**Update**

As you've outlined, the way you want to show your data is to display it based on dependent data. To do this, you need to be able to call the data when required, but you should just be able to use what you've got:

```
#app/views/application/index.html.erb
<%= render partial: "list", locals: { items: @provinces } %>

#app/views/application/_list.html.erb
<ul>
    <% items.each do |item| %>
        <li>
            <%= item.name %>
            <%= render partial: "list", locals: {items: item.districts} if item.districts.present? %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

This will allow you to output the items you need with the relevant data

Comment: Okay - what are your requirements specifically? The models I outlined will give you the ability to associate all the data, how would you like to *structure* it with `ancestry`?

Comment: Okay, i want website like this way appear like http://bikroy.com/en, Rich Peck can you suggest me..

Comment: Okay - you don't actually need the `ancestry` gem, *or* `acts_as_tree` to do this - you'll need to use your associations. Let me explain in an update for you!

Comment: this my scaffold controller,   def create
    [at]district = District.new(district_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if [at]district.save
        format.html { redirect_to [at]district, notice: 'District was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: [at]district }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: [at]district.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end  @RichPeck, what i want to do

Comment: what iam want to do in DistrictsController < ApplicationController or  CitiesController < ApplicationController

Comment: It depends on what you want to show! What is it you wish to show from these controllers?

Comment: I want admin can create province and cities & districts

Comment: And association them all under tree structer

Comment: Just use the same CRUD structure as you would other controllers, and you'll have to authorize for the admin - probably with the CanCan gem

Comment: I added cancan , also CRUD province, city & district. Then i want when admin create one city how going below to district? how district going to below province

Comment: create_table "cities", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "district_id"
  end

  add_index "cities", ["district_id"], name: "index_cities_on_district_id"

  create_table "districts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "province_id"
  end

  add_index "districts", ["province_id"], name: "index_districts_on_province_id"

  create_table "provinces", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
     end

Comment: add schema.rb association

Comment: That really doesn't help in any way - you need to firstly update the question with actual information, then ask on here for help. How the hell am I meant to know what you want to achieve from posting a migration like that in the comments/